# What would Lupin see in the Mirror of Erised?

Tags: harry-potter, remus-lupin

I have a deep interest in knowing what the characters in the Wizarding world would see in the **Mirror of Erised**.

Is there any indication of what Remus Lupin would see in the Mirror?

Comment: I've edited the question so it's no longer asking for opinions, but actual canon information. Opinion-based questions are off-topic here and on pretty much every other Stack Exchange site. That still leaves the issue noted by the other commentators, but it's up to you to decide which character you want this question to be about, and which character to ask about in a separate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There is no canon information on what Lupin would see.

In the books nor the films does Lupin ever look into the Mirror of Erised.

I've also searched *Accio Quote* and *[Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-mirror-of-erised)*. The only thing remotely related to Lupin's desires, is the following quote by J.K. Rowling from [a 2003 interview by Stephen Fry](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2003/0626-alberthall-fry.htm) at the Royal Albert Hall:

> [...]  Lupin’s failing is he likes to be liked. That’s where he slips up – he’s been disliked so often he’s always pleased to have friends so cuts them an awful lot of slack.

---

But let's not forget, the Mirror of Erised is not a cloakroom mirror, just standing somewhere. It's a unique magical item, and not entirely harmless. As Dumbledore tells Harry:

> "Men have wasted away before it, not knowing if what they have seen is real, or even possible."

So it's not likely that many people have been able to take look, Lupin being among the many who have never even laid eyes upon it.

Comment: This is what I needed! Small price to pay for salvation 